# Unable to get latest of a Web view on local machine

Tags: cmd, automation, case, cleartool

I am trying to take latest using `cleartool update` command but it throws an error saying "`abc`"  is not a valid snapshot view path, maybe because mine is not a snapshot view but rather a Web view.

How can I get latest of Web view?

My view is `C:\CCRC\WKB`
Actual view on server looks something like `//aet/ccase/vws1/s123/dev.po.vws`

How should I write the command to get the latest Web view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "[About ClearCase views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm)"

> A web view is a copy-based ClearCase view that is tolerant of high-latency connections to a CCRC WAN server, although it may be used in both wide-area network (WAN) and local area network (LAN) environments.
>   In other respects, web views are similar to snapshot views

[`cleartool update`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) is supposed to work with web views.

> ClearCase Remote Client—Update elements in a web view from the command line:

```
update [ –print ] [ –ove/rwrite | –nov/erwrite | –ren/ame ] [ –ptime ] [ pname ... ]
```

The issue here is that the real snapshot view that is created by ccweb and resides on the web server where ccweb is running.
You would need to access the view on the server side for a `cleartool update` to run.

Try instead to use **[rcleartool](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929)** (see [getting started with rcleartool](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728)) in order to script a `rcleartool update` for a web view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Well, this means I should be able to take latest on the server using cleartool, right? But on server as well, I face the same issue. Can you please suggest exactly what path do I need to provide to this command?

Comment: @TyagiP No the update is supposed to take place on your workstation, not on the server. You need to use `rcleartool`.