# How to update Clear Case view using .Net?

Tags: c#, api, clearcase-automation

I want to automatically update my ClearCase view.

What kind of call do I need to make in my C# code?
Could CAL perform an Update function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAL indeed (see "[Using Perl with Rational ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4711.html)"), but more in a Perl script.

See as example of Perl script [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/nov01/changeset_report.txt) or [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193934/6309).

That means your C# code [should run a `Process.Start()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206347/6309)

That should complete [your previous question about update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018868/6309).